# Debugging a Kivy android app using BlueStacks

Tags: android, debugging, android-emulator, kivy, bluestacks

I'm building my apk using Buildozer in Ubuntu. But I am more comfortable using BlueStacks in Windows for the testing purpose. My app crashes after it starts with no apparent signals. How can I debug it using BlueStacks?

Answer (score 1):

There's a debug tool with file name: `HD-Adb.exe` in `Program Files` (`Program Files (x86)` in Win64) path of BlueStacks. When you run this tool, you could see all what happens behind the android emulator. It's easy to debug your app then. To run the tool open command line in Windows and type the following lines:

```
> cd "c:\Program Files (x86)\BlueStacks"
c:\Program Files (x86)\BlueStacks>HD-Adb.exe logcat
```

I really had hard time trying android sdk emulator and other things. But this works great! Enjoy debugging.

Comment: adb is a standard tool that comes with the android SDK, you can run it on both windows and linux. You can also run `buildozer logcat` to use the version installed by buildozer, which may not otherwise be in your `$PATH`.